# Не перезагружается nginx в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, bash

С конфигурационными файлами все в порядке.

```
root@maxserver:~# nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t**
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

При попытке перечитать конфиг файл пишет такое.

```
root@maxserver:~# kill -HUP `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
-bash: kill: (5289) - No such process
```

Если перезагружать то пишет fail

```
root@maxserver:~# sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx                                [fail] 
root@maxserver:~#
```

В чем может быть причина?
Почему он сообщает, что bash - нет такого процесса?

Comment: Ну раз `fail`, значит он запущен не был, а потому и `No such process`. Вы ошибки-то посмотрите, там написано должно быть что не так. У вас может апач на там же порту весит, на котором nginx запустить пытаетесь.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Когда `nginx` завершается аварийно, то он не очищает `pid` в `/var/run/nginx.pid`, следовательно id процесса остался, а сам процесс давно умер.

Чтоб посмотреть почему nginx не стартует, выполни в консоли от рута

```
$ nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

В эту же консоль и напишет почему не может запустится.

Если напишет

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

То значит кто-то уже занял данный порт, посмотреть кто его занял можно выполнив команду

```
$ netstat -apn | grep "0:80"
```

Ключи:

```
 -a :на всех интерфейсах машины
 -p :показывать PID и имя программы
 -n :показывать IP вместо резолва в хостнейм
```

Вывод будет похож на следующий:

```
$ netstat -lapn | grep "0:80"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2601/nginx
```

В последнем столбце и показан PID/имя процесса который использует порт.

Ну и всегда полезно посмотреть логи самого nginx. Они находятся по умолчанию в `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.